# Stick-breaking random walk

Tags: probability-theory, random-walk, law-of-large-numbers

> Let $(X_n : n = 1,2, \ldots)$ be an i.i.d. sequence of random variables uniformly distributed on $(0,1)$. For $n = 0, 1,2, \ldots$ , set
>   $$ S_n = \prod_{k=1}^{n} X_k$$. Calculate $E(S_n)$. Compare $S_n$ and $E(S_n)$ for large n.

I tried this:

First $E(S_n)=E(\prod_{k=1}^{n} X_k) = \prod_{k=1}^{n} E(X_k)=_{uniformly} 2^{-n}$ then $E(S_n)=2^{-n}$  Is it correct?

Second I'm trying to apply the Strong Law of Large Numbers to the sequence dened by $$\log S_n = \log ( \prod_{k=1}^{n}X_k) = \sum_{k=1}^{n} \log X_k$$
 then $$ \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{\log S_n}{n} =\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{\sum_{k=1}^{n} \log X_k}{n} $$

but here I stuck I don't know How to continue this exercise....

Could someone help to compare this $S_n$ and $E(S_n)$ for large n? Pls.

Thanks for your time and help.

Comment: Yea, sorry. I edited.

Comment: What does "stick-breaking random walk" mean?

Comment: Its¡ is the name of the exercise. The sequence $(S_n)$ is a randorn walk on the state space (0,1], which is a sernigroup under the operation of ordinary rnultiplication

Comment: So what does that have to do with breaking sticks? [PS: Your computation of $E[S_n]=1/2^n$ seems fine, but I do not know what your "uniformly" means in the middle of your equation.  Your use of LLN is also fine (to conclude the $\log(S_n)/n \rightarrow E[\log(X_1)]$, perhaps to conclude $S_n/e^{-n} \rightarrow 1$ ?]

Comment: Another exercise says that Describe the sequence $(S_n)$
in terms of the successive lengths of the remaining part of a stick whose original length was one.

Comment: $\log S_n$ should be a normal distribution by the CLT, right?

Comment: But For now I'm trying to compare $S_n$ and $E(S_n)$

Comment: what is CLT?.... and why  normal distr?

Comment: @Michael Yea ahmmm cause I applied the fact that $S_n$ is uniformly distributed and then $S_n = 1/2^n$ but why $log(S_n)/n \rightarrow E[logX_1]$?

Comment: That would be applying the LLN to hte iid random varaibles $\{\log(X_i)\}$.  I should not have concluded $S_n/e^{-n}\rightarrow 1$, more like $S_n \approx e^{-n}$ in a sense.

Comment: Is $S_n$ almost zero? as its mean?

Comment: Intuitively we know the product of numbers in $(0,1)$ must decrease and, since there is a probability $1/2$ the next number will be less than $1/2$, the overall product should go to zero (wp1).

Comment: why $ \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{\log S_n}{n} =\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{\sum_{k=1}^{n} \log X_k}{n}  = E(\log X_1)$?

Comment: I do not get your question.   You yourself proved that $\frac{\log(S_n)}{n} = \frac{\sum_{k=1}^n \log(X_k)}{n}$, so you can take limits of both sides.  Or are you asking about using LLN (law of large numbers)?  Do you know the statement of the LLN? Perhaps you could state it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your computation for $E[S_n]$ appears to be correct. So let's discuss $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^n \log X_k$

What is $E[\log X_1]$? It's $\int_{0}^{1} \log x dx$, which visually looks like this:[image]

It's obvious from the picture that we can think of the integral in terms of the exponential function: that is, $\int_{0}^{1} \log x dx = -\int_{-\infty}^0 e^x dx = -\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-x} dx = -1$, so by the SLLN, $\frac{1}{n}\log S_N = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^n \log X_k \to E[\log X_1] = -1$ almost surely, and $\log S_n = n \left(\frac{1}{n}\log S_n\right) \to -\infty$ almost surely (this is true since $\lim_{n \to \infty} n \left(\frac{1}{n}\log S_n\right) = \left(\lim_{n \to \infty} n\right) \left(\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(\frac{1}{n}\log S_n\right)\right) = -1 \times \left(\lim_{n \to \infty} n\right)$ almost surely), so $S_n \to e^{-\infty} = 0$ almost surely, which agrees with the limit of the expected value of $S_n$.

Comment: Since almost sure convergence implies convergence in probability, we conclude that, for any $\epsilon >0$, $$ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} P(\{\omega: e^{-(1+\epsilon)n}<S_n<e^{-(1-\epsilon)n}\})=1$$ Thus, with high probability $E(S_n)/S_n$ is very large for large ?

Comment: for large $n$....